# Долгий ответ сервера при первой загрузке страницы

Tags: nginx

Доброго времени суток. Перевожу один проект на nginx. И возникла странная штука. Проверяя страницы в PageSpeed я обнаружил, что при первой проверка система говорит, что ответ сервера слишком долгий, а при повторной проверке все норм, предупреждение не выскакивает. С чем может это быть связано?

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
    access_log off;

    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    keepalive_timeout               30;
    keepalive_requests 100;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 2;
    directio 250m;
    expires max;
    limit_rate 350K;
    client_max_body_size            128m;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         900;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            900;
    fastcgi_send_timeout            900;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
    }
```

Comment: Что такое «портовая проверка»? Повторная?

Comment: Упсс.. Да, повторная проперка

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это связано именно с nginx?

Comment: Как вариант задержки: первое обращение к серверу - создание кэша запрошенного uri + ответ на запрос. Повторное обращение - получение ответа уже из готового кэша.

Comment: Тогда стоит искать проблему в связке FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)?

Comment: Сделайте тест сами. Если после рестарта nginx-a ваше первое обращение к серверу не особо отличается от повторного по времени загрузки (я имею ввиду открыть сайт своим браузером), то может этот измеритель пэйдж-спид врет и у вас все отлично. Если же картина повторится, то могут быть варианты.

Comment: Типичная проблема кеширования. Где-то создаётся кеш php, который потом выдаётся быстро.

Comment: Теперь бы понять где кешируется, почему и как это выключить

Comment: Зачем же кеширование выключать?